# Are there any recent studies on vowels of PRS?

Tags: phonology, phonetics, dialects, spanish

Consonants and their phenomena are well studied for PRS (Puerto Rican Spanish). However, vowels and their phenomena are less well known. Known vowel phenomena in the dialect are unstressed/final vowel raising (in montainous areas; once more widespread, reaching Vieques), final vowel devoicing and elision (in the northeast and east), and rounding assimilation in rising diphthongs with /w/ (plus sometimes reduction of rounding-assimilated /we̞/ to [ø̞]). However, there is no recent research that I know of concerning the vowels of PRS (except the vowel raising phenomenon) and the possible impact of English (specifically American English) on PRS vowel quality. So, is there any recent research on PRS vowels?